# My mouse pointer not accurate in my canvas app.(html) -FIXED

Tags: javascript, json, canvas

in my painting app in html my mouse pointer is not accurate. it works perfect but when i start drawing the actual color will be bellow the pointer and to the right a bit. take a look for yourself.

```
<a href="http://jsfiddle.net/daniel9000/egpr99k9/">DEMO</a>
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Wouldnt let me insert url for some reason so had to put it like that. just copy the url.sorry

Ignor the colors not working(its just a glitch with JSFiddle)

Comment: It won't let you add the link because you haven't added any code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The position reported by the mouse event is relative to the entire window, not to where you have placed your canvas element.

I used JQuery to get the position of your canvas element and use that to offset your mouse position.  Perhaps someone else can chime in with a pure javascript solution.

Put

```
var p = $("#canvas").position();
```

above your putPoint function.

Then, inside your putPoint function do this

```
var mouseX = e.clientX + p.left;
var mouseY = e.clientY - p.top;
```

OK, figured out my stupidity.  Instead of JQuery you can just do this inside your putPoint function.

```
var mouseX = e.clientX + canvas.offsetLeft;
var mouseY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
```

Comment: Upvote for your concise and useful answer! BTW, you can also use `canvas.getBoundingClientRect()` which contains `.top` and `.left` properties adjusted for page scrolling.

Comment: Could you show me exaclty where to put them because when im putting them in it doesnt let me draw. i feel like im doing something wrong.

Comment: @Daniel Adams, I updated your fiddle instead of adding to the answer here, which has already been marked as a duplicate.  I switched to using getBoundsClientRect as suggested by MarkE. http://jsfiddle.net/egpr99k9/5/

Comment: @HeadCode, Thankyou sooooo muuch for taking your time to help me, i realy appreciate it, But it seems the Y coordinates are fixed but the x has not. it is inline with the paint but the paint appears to the right of the cursor now

Comment: I saw that but figured it had something to do with the JSFiddle.  I couldn't figure out the actual cause, but this will fix it: var mouseX = e.clientX + bounds.left - 20;